# Android Java 'A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released'

Tags: java, android, httpclient, html

I would like to grab the HTML code of a webpage, and display it in an edittext control, but i end up with this error:

> 1482-1491/android.process.acore E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired
>   at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for
>   information on avoiding resource leaks.

This is my code:

```
   class GetResult implements Runnable {
    private volatile String bodyHtml;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String myUri = "http://www.google.com";
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(myUri);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

            bodyHtml = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            //return bodyHtml;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            bodyHtml = "kapot";
        }

    }

    public String getbodyHtml(){
        return bodyHtml;
    }


}
```

and

```
                String rs = "";
                GetResult foo = new GetResult();
                new Thread(foo).start();
                rs = foo.getbodyHtml();
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I havent looked into your code to much, but just look for any Closable objects, and close them once you are done with em. (Maybe its HttpResponse?)

Comment: Close your resources.

Comment: Note that your code will not work, as you are calling `getbodyHtml()` well before it will have been downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close httpClient in a finally block. Like so:

```
public void run() {
    HttpClient httpClient = null
    try {
        String myUri = "http://www.google.com";
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(myUri);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

        bodyHtml = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        //return bodyHtml;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        bodyHtml = "kapot";
    } finally {
        if (httpClient != null) { 
           httpClient.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `} catch (IOException e) {  bodyHtml = "kapot";   }` Awful exception catch. **Always** log the stacktrace.